# Wifi, Ethernet, Bluetooth no longer available

Tags: wireless, 16.04, updates, network-manager

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 since April with no issues whatsoever. After the last automatic system update, neither my wifi, ethernet or bluetooth seem to be working anymore.

I have a Fujitsu Lifebook A Series Laptop with an Intel Wireless 7260 Wireless device. I have tried the basic networkmanager restarts etc, but nothing is working for me.

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Wait for Chili555 or Pilot6, and they'll help you out.

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: Also edit to include results for `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`  Hold the Shift key during reboot until the Grub menu appears, then select advanced options and boot using an older kernel and see if you have things functioning so that you can post results

Comment: @chili555 - when I do run sudo modprobe iwlwifi, there is no output, not sure what that means though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answers, much appreciated. So I have figured this out, it seems that it was related to linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic or 4.4.0-43.63.

I did what @Jeremy31 suggested, and then chose to boot into linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic. I then did a system update, which seems to have transitioned to the next (or different) image increment, namely 4.4.0.43.45, and everything seems to work again, so it *looks* like the issue is related to the specific update version.